# Showing selected image in alert dialog in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can i show the selected image in my alert dialog ?

In my app, i added an alert dialog which has the camera button. When user clicks the camera button, another alert dialog asks to select file from gallery. After the user selects image file from gallery, i want to show the image in the alert dialog with the camera button, but the image shows only after reopening the alert dialog.

I have posted my code below. I am new to flutter. Please can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _State createState() => new _State();
}
Future<File> imageFile;
class _State extends State<Test> {
  Future<void> _openDailog() async {

    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: true,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          shape:
          RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Click Photo'),
              Ink(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
                    color: Colors.blue),
                child: IconButton(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _cameraOptions();
                   print("test");
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              width: 300.0,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  showImage(),
                  InkWell(
                      child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          child: new Text(
                            "Send",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            print("test");
                          },
                        ),
                      )),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return  Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        FloatingActionButton(
        heroTag: null,
        child: Icon(Icons.insert_drive_file),
        onPressed: () {
          _openDailog();
        },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
  Future<void> _cameraOptions() {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: new SingleChildScrollView(
              child: new ListBody(
                children: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      pickImageFromGallery(ImageSource.gallery);
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    child: new Text(
                      'Select From Gallery',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                      style: new TextStyle(
                        decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
  pickImageFromGallery(ImageSource source) {
    setState(() {
      imageFile = ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
    });
  }
  Widget showImage() {
    return FutureBuilder<File>(
      future: imageFile,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<File> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
            snapshot.data != null) {
          return Image.file(
            snapshot.data,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: 100,
          );
        } else if (snapshot.error != null) {
          return const Text(
            'Error Picking Image',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          );
        } else {
          return const Text(
            'No Image Selected',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you would need to `setState()` however you can't do that in an alert dialogue as it doesn't have its own state, the workaround for that would be to have the dialogue be its own stateful widget. Please check out [this article](https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/05/hint-5-how-to-refresh-the-content-of-a-dialog-via-setstate/) as it shows how to do that. If you faced problems let me know!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyHomePage(),
  ));
}


class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("StackoverFlow"),
      ),
      body: Container(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          await _dialogCall(context);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _dialogCall(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return MyDialog();
        });
  }
}


class MyDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyDialogState createState() => new _MyDialogState();
}

class _MyDialogState extends State<MyDialog> {

  String imagePath;
  Image image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      content: new SingleChildScrollView(
        child: new ListBody(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(child: image!= null? image:null),
            GestureDetector(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(Icons.camera),
                    SizedBox(width: 5),
                    Text('Take a picture                       '),
                  ],
                ),
                onTap: () async {
                  await getImageFromCamera();
                  setState(() {

                  });
                }),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  Future getImageFromCamera() async {
    var x = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    imagePath = x.path;
    image = Image(image: FileImage(x));
  }

}
```

Comment: I did try by viewing the same article before but I couldnt work around that code. Can you so me how can i do so for an image?

Comment: Alright just please let me know which package are you importing in the pubspec.yaml and i'll write you a sample code

Comment: The dependencies are :   image_picker: ^0.4.5
  path_provider: ^1.1.0

Comment: sorry i took long i had to go eat. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I'm glad! let me know if you faced other problems

Comment: I was able to work this for image from gallery but the camera one doesn't show the image even after saving it in pictures. Do you know why?

Comment: Show me your code, the example i showed you have the image taken from camera and it works perfectly fine, follow the example and you should be good to go

Comment: i have the same code as yours except i commented the x.path line . The container is shown but image is blank.

Comment: and do you know why it crashes on android 9 after taking picture?

Comment: I have never tried this on android 9 so I'm not quite sure

Answer (score 0):

> Try this solution with GestureDetector() .it works

```
onTap:()async{
var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
source: ImageSource.gallery).whenComplete((){
      setState(() { 
      });
  }
  );
 setState(() {
  _image = image;
  });

 },
```

Comment: what do we do in the first setState? it's empty and I'm having similar challenges as the author of this question. Could you explain further?
Thanks.

Comment: if you want to perform any operation after selecting image then use whenComplete otherwise, you can remove whenComplete and first setState

Comment: It doesn't work for me still. I asked a question regarding this here. Think you can have a look? Thanks.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64090080/working-with-imager-picker-dependency-in-flutter

Comment: I will update your code in your question, please check @hermie_brown

Comment: Thanks I changed my image declaration type from File to var like you did here.

Comment: I also post the working code in your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64090080/working-with-imager-picker-dependency-in-flutter .try that and upvote if the solution works for you