# Working with Imager Picker Dependency in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, imagepicker

I have a function in my application that helps the user pick Image from gallery or take a photo with camera.

```
  _getImage(ImageSource source) async {
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    File selectedImage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
      source: source,
      imageQuality: 50,
      maxWidth: 400.0,
    ).whenComplete(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    if (_imageFile == null) return;
    
    setState(() {
      _imageFile = selectedImage;
    });
  }
```

I am using this [image_picker dependency](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) and I followed the example I found therein and also examples of possible updates done by others online. From a suggestion on [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56885714/showing-selected-image-in-alert-dialog-in-flutter/61011084?noredirect=1#comment113307025_61011084), I'm advised to add the whenComplete therein, which I did.

When I select an image from my gallery, it doesn't update the image view widget in my screen. Neither does the camera option work. What could I possibly be missing?

Here's my Image widget that displays the image:

```
return Stack(
    alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
    children: <Widget>[
      Image.file(
        _imageFile,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        height: 250,
      ),
      Container(
        width: 250.0,
        height: 100.0,
        color: Colors.black54,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Change Image',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 22.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                //camera button
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.camera),
                  onPressed: () => _getImage(ImageSource.camera),
                  color: kThemeStyleButtonFillColour,
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 20.0),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.fileImport),
                  onPressed: () => _getImage(ImageSource.gallery),
                  color: kThemeStyleButtonFillColour,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 32.0),
    ],
  );
```

Comment: First of all stop using pickImage as it is deprecated. Use `final pickedFile = ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);` this returns a `pickedFile` and can be converted to File using `imageFile = File(pickedFile.Path)`

Comment: Please share the code snippet that contains `Image widget` and declaration of `_imageFile` variable.

Comment: getImage doesn't work for me as it wants me to cast it as a File. Only pickImage does even though it says it's deprecated so I suppress warnings. 

This is the error getImage() gives:
A value of type 'PickedFile' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'File'.

Comment: I have edited my question to add the Image widget that displays it.

Comment: Found the issue, check my answer, hopefully it will resolve your issue. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong logic inside `if` statement.

Right way to do this,

`if(selectedImage != null) { Update image widget here }`

I think `imageFile` variable has not been assigned any file initially so the condition `imageFile == null` is always true and the image widget is never updated.

Answer (score 2):

** I will update your code, try this**

```
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class check extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _checkState createState() => _checkState();
}

class _checkState extends State<check> {
  File _imageFile;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Stack(
      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
      children: <Widget>[
        _imageFile !=null ? Image.file(
          _imageFile ,
          height: 250,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ) : Text('No image selected.'),
        SizedBox(height: 100,),
        Container(
          width: 250.0,
          height: 100.0,
          color: Colors.black54,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Change Image',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 22.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  //camera button
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.camera),
                    onPressed: () => _getImage(ImageSource.camera),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 20.0),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.attach_file),
                    onPressed: () => _getImage(ImageSource.gallery),

                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 32.0),
      ],
    )
    );
  }

  _getImage(ImageSource source) async {
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    File selectedImage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
      source: source,
      imageQuality: 50,
      maxWidth: 400.0,
    );

    setState(() {
      _imageFile = selectedImage;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case,

```
   setState(() {
      _imageFile = selectedImage;
    });
```

Is not waiting for the selected image

Try this:

```
   _getImage(ImageSource source) async {
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    File selectedImage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
      source: source,
      imageQuality: 50,
      maxWidth: 400.0,
    );
    setState(() {
         _imageFile = selectedImage;
     });
  }
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work either. Because we can't assign selectedImage a value when it's not complete. So I declared it first as File selectedImage; then I used selected Image = await .......

But I still can't change the image in the display.

Comment: If you use await you no need use when complete. I will update the code.

Comment: You're right. whenComplete no longer makes sense if I'm await-ing. However this doesn't do the magic still. I'm testing on iPhone 11 Pro. 

I finally got it to work by changing the selectedImage type from File to var. Doesn't make sense but that's what did it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this code to work and the hack still beats me because it doesn't sense.

I followed the recommendation given above by doing away with whenComplete since there's an await.

I also changed the declaration type of selectedImage from File to var as below:

```
  _getImage(ImageSource source) async {
    var selectedImage;
    selectedImage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
      source: source,
      imageQuality: 50,
      maxWidth: 400.0,
    );

    setState(() {
      _imageFile = selectedImage;
    });
  }
```

Doesn't make sense why var worked and File didn't since we know we're expecting a File as returned value, but it works well now.

Comment: I think the issue was the if statement you have used previous, because the condition didn't make any sense. I would also recommend to replace pickImage with getImage, read the documents for assistance. There is a section dedicated for this update in the docs https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

Comment: Yes you're right, thanks. I just read the docs and found the recommended way to use getImage. Thanks!